# React onClick event only triggerable once after compiling from jsx to js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that builds a list of images with 2 buttons on each array entry.

One of the 2 buttons has an onClick event which updates its parentComponent so that the image is shown in a bigger view.

Everything works perfectly in the precompilex jsx version. But as soon as i try out the "live" compiled version the onClick event only works once.

To make it work on another element I need to reload the page.

I don't get any console errors. No idea where the error might be.

If you want to recreate it you can paste the code and create a div with the id "bilder".

I am using the latest react version :

```
<script src="some-react-CDN-0.13.3.js"></script>
<script src="some-react-CDN/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
```

Heres the source :

```
var Bilder = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data:[
              ['1', '/app/public/imgs/image.jpg', 'bild1.jpg'],
              ['2', '/app/public/imgs/image.jpg', 'bild2.jpg'],
              ['3', '/app/public/imgs/image.jpg', 'bild3.jpg'],
              ['4', '/app/public/imgs/image.jpg', 'bild4.jpg'],
              ['5', '/app/public/imgs/image.jpg', 'bild5.jpg']
          ],
      currentPic:[],
      display:'showBild clearfix dn',
      displayBg:'darkBg dn'
    };
  },
  showBild: function(e, data){
    this.setState({
      currentPic: e,
      display: 'showBild clearfix db',
      displayBg: 'darkBg db'
    });
  },
  hide: function(){
    this.setState({
      display: 'showBild clearfix dn',
      displayBg: 'darkBg dn'
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SingleBild data={this.state.data} chosenBild={this.showBild} />
        <BildDetail hide={this.hide} data={this.state.currentPic} display={this.state.display} displayBg={this.state.displayBg} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var SingleBild = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      bild:[]
    };
  },
  showBild: function(data, e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.chosenBild(data);
  },
  render: function() {
    var scopeThis = this;
    var displayBild = function(bild){
         return <li><img src={bild[1]} alt="" /><span>{bild[2]}</span><a onClick={scopeThis.showBild.bind(null, bild)} href="#"><i className="fa fa-eye"></i></a><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></li>
    };
    return (
      <ul className="dashboardUl bilder clearfix">
        <h2>Gemeldete Bilder:</h2>
        {this.props.data.map(displayBild)}
      </ul>
    );
  }

});
var BildDetail  = React.createClass({
  hide: function(){
    this.props.hide();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={this.props.display}>
          <img src={this.props.data[1]} alt="" />
          <span>{this.props.data[2]}</span>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-ban"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div onClick={this.hide} className={this.props.displayBg}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<Bilder />, document.getElementById('bilder'));
```

Comment: try just `this.showBild` since the evenHandler is autobound. And get rid of  `var scopeThis = this;`

Comment: If I get rid of scopeThis it doesnt work at all because the scope of the this is different in the map function
I have to use it like that ..

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove the mapping of data onto list nodes out of the return statement in `render` and then bind component Class to to the map callback function.

```
...
render: function() {
  var listNodes = this.props.data.map(function(bild) {
    return (
      <li>
         <img src={bild[1]} alt="" />
         <span>{bild[2]}</span>
         <a onClick={this.showBild} href="#">
           <i className="fa fa-eye"></i>
         </a>
         <a href="#">
           <i className="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
         </a>
       </li>
    )
  }.bind(this));

  return (
    <ul className="dashboardUl bilder clearfix">
      <h2>Gemeldete Bilder:</h2>
      {listNodes}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Now

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't solve the issue. Let me specify my issue again: the array gets mapped through perfectly - > I get all <li></li> with its content. The issue is that the a tag with the onClick event only works once on one li and not on the other ones. When I keep everything uncompiled and use the facebook live compiler it works perfectly for all list elements ...

Comment: I understand, and I the issue is to do with context binding. Just out of curiosity, it there any logged in your console when you try to click it the second time?

Comment: Thanks for that hint - No idea why i didn't add a console log in the onClick function. It seems that the onClick function gets triggered. It also works that the prop of the component calls the function in the parent component but I do also get a console.log at "showBild function" but the setState doesnt seem to work more than once